# Error message in VS2013 Ultimate edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm getting the following error message

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MarshalingWindowFrame'.

This message came when I tried to load a SLN file into VS2013.

What is the reason?

I am using VS2013 Ultimate with Update 4 on Windows8.1 pro x64 bit OS (8GB RAM, 500GB HDD)

Answer (score 0):

If you get that when opening a solution, either an addon is bugging out or (worse, but less likely) you found a bug in VS itself. Try safe mode and see if that helps.

If however you get the error when opening a *form* rather than the solution itself (remember opening a solution loads the various forms), there's a bug in an user control that's trying to access a disposed object. Remember that user controls run as binaries when hosted in VS, so make sure you put actual code inside guards that require you not to be in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Was that project created in the earlier versions or in the Visual Studio 2013 Preview? Because, if you update this project from Visual Studio 2013 Preview, you have to check the update procedure (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2013/08/12/upgrading-your-lightswitch-projects-raghuveer-gopalakrishnan.aspx) first, perhaps it can give some hints why this happens.